# NotificationCenter not called in CollectionViewCell did select

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I have a collectionview cell for to display some labels, when I do didselect I have to fire a notification using 'NSNotificationCenter' with the label name to another viewcontroller . But when i select a label in collectioncell , The notification is read, but not triggered to another viewcontroller. Can anyone suggest me a solution

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *SearchTag;
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)[_taglinkarray[indexPath.row] count] ; i++)
    {
        if([[_taglinkarray[indexPath.row][i] valueForKey:@"profileFieldType"] isEqualToString:@"certificate"])
        {
            SearchTag = _tagarray[indexPath.row];
            NSLog(@"tag name ------->%@",_tagarray[indexPath.row]);
             NSDictionary * dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:SearchTag forKey:@"Tags"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NOTIFICATION" object:nil userInfo:dict];
        }
    }



}


In Another VC
//In DidLoad()
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(receivedNotification:)
                                                 name:@"NOTIFICATION" object:nil];

-(void)receivedNotification:(NSNotification*) notification
{
    NSLog(@"Notification  Received ");
}
```

Comment: Could you Please show your code ?

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you should use "NSDictionary *dict = @{@"Tags": SearchTag};" to create your dictionary.  The updated syntax is shorter and easier to read.

Comment: working fine you print notification like this. -(void)receivedNotification:(NSNotification*) notification{NSLog( @"%@", notification.userInfo);  NSLog(@"Notification  Received");}

Comment: Its not even going to that viewcontroller did load

Comment: I have a tableview, inside which I have a collectionview . I have used xib files to implement this. I am calling this collectionview didselect , which is inside my tableviewcell... Will the notification work when its in tableviewcell class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you didSelected a cell, and you post a notification ,but another UIViewController is not alloc this time , so you are not receive a  notification,

Comment: How can i call it?

Comment: you can alloc a new viewController directly without notification

Comment: I already have code in that viewcontroller, just have to pass the label value to another viewcontroller to filter

Comment: Are you not receive notification or not  push the new page?

Comment: Nope, it didn't respond to that notification call in didselect

Comment: You know that addObserver must before the post notification,

Comment: You are right..My problem solved .. thanks @taitanxiami :)